# Dynamic Nested Loops for Autofilter in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program setup to spit out a specific summary.  Now I want to take that program and allow it to accept user inputted ranges.  I have it down to 2 levels but it gets conceptually hard for me to go further, though I am using a 3D array to store the values.

Away from my work computer but its something like,

```
Dim array1(3) As String 'Fill it with some values like Group1, Group2, Group3...
Dim array2(4) As String 'Again the next level with some values like NY, PA,..., Total
Dim arVal(3,5,4) as Long 'For each Group 1, it will summarize 5 fields for each item in arr2

For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
   Autofilter based on array1
   For j = LBound(array2) to UBound(array2)
      If Not j = 4
          Autofilter based on array2
      EndIf
      arVal(i, 0, j) = Value
      arVal(i, 1, j) = Value
      ...
   Next j
Next i
```

One idea I have is to use linked lists, where there will be the 1st list where each subsequent list will chain to each node in the list.  Only problem is i only conceptually learned about linked lists in C++ so while this may be a solution I have no clue on how to implement this in VBA.

**Addition:**

> array1 = {Group 1, Group 2, .... Total}
>   array2 = {Northeast, West, Southeast....}
>   arVal(1, 1, 1) = For all people within Group 1 in the Northeast Region the Sum of Potatoes bought(Value 1)
>   arVal(1, 1, 2) = For all people within Group 1 in the Northeast Region the unique count of people(Value 2)

and then it goes on to

> arVal(1, 2, 1) = For all people within Group 1 in the WEST region the Sum of Potatoes....
>   and so forth such that for each group, I want to summarize each of the regions within that group.

The problem arises if I want to dynamically add more subcategories under the regions.

So I guess the main question is if given an integer, to create a nested loop equal to that integer such that:

```
If i = 2
{ For Each item in Group
     For Each item in Regions
         some function
}
If i = 3
{ For Each item in Group
     For Each item in Regions
        For Each item in NextSubcategory
           some function
}
```

Though I could limit the amount of subcategories one could go and use a switch statement, the program would be more robust if dynamic.  Plus the impending aneurysm if I try to use multidimensional arrays to store the values.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain it better? For example, user sets range to A1:A10, then what? Or is this something completely different? Depending on the summary you are calculating, the method you should/could do it will change. For example, a 3D array may not be appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand what @riotburn is trying to accomplish, either.

Comment: here is a link to a picture I drew. http://i56.tinypic.com/5exqaa.jpg

Comment: okay now how does value1 value2 east west etc relate to arVal array1 and array2 in your code. once that is clear solving your problem should be fairly simple

Comment: Are you summarizing or filtering?  That is, does the user say "summarize on group and region" or "summarize on group, region, state"?  Or is the user saying "show me records for Group1 and Group2, Northeast and West, and NY, MA, WA, AZ"?  Where is the source data? How is laid out?  My gut says disconnected recordset, but I need more info to be sure.

Comment: I am summarizing based on filtered data.  Basically array1 and array2 (all the fields on the vertical axis) are values to filter the data by.  So it would be filter first by array1[1] then by array2[i], filtering through all the values within array2 while still holding the filter created by array1[1].  After that is done it goes to array1[2] and again filters through array2.  
The data is in columns, where a record pertains to one row.  Though there are columns that only contain a few unique values like groups and regions on which the data can be summarized.

Comment: I just got the summary part of this program working, where what I hope to accomplish is for each item in array1 and array2...arrayX, is to have an array(X, 2) where for each filter value is an associated array of summarized values.  
  
    1. Group 1 , (50, 100,...2000)  
    2. Region1 , (25, 15,....1000)  
    3. Region2 , (25, 85,....1000)  

Where you see group1 is a subtotal of regions 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

On the topic of Linked lists in VBA this may be useful to you.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

You could then follow the methodology you used in C++ to create a linked list using the VBA class.

Edit: this may also help [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227473%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

Comment: but is my idea right? and can linked lists be implemented in vba?

Comment: yes linked lists can be implemented in vba using vba classes with a member with the same type as the class eg. `Private nextNode As Node` assuming your class was called Node.  you would then need to implement a property let and get method (covered in the link). I'm not 100% sure as to what you wish to achieve, perhaps if you gave an example of the output you were looking for.

Comment: for a lack of a better effort to draw a table in the comment box...the idea is sort of along the pivottable concept where if you put two items in the row label, the lower ordered is summarized for each item in the higher level.  Though I am doing it in VBA one to automate it, two to include some functions not available in pivots.
How do I post a pic on here?

Comment: To post a picture you need > 10 reputation. My understanding at this point is. Row 1 is lets say months, jan -> dec if Row 2 is sales you wish to have all the sales from jan totaled in the cell below the name of the month. Is this correct?

Comment: link to picture I drew of the desired end result http://i56.tinypic.com/5exqaa.jpg

Comment: Unless you need a highly customized linked list, there's generally no need to implement your own in VBA when you have structures like Collections and Scripting.Dictionary.  You can store objects in both of those object types and one of those should fill the function of a linked list.