# Dynamic Nested For Loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic, recursion

First off, I apologize for starting a new thread but the original got confusing because I couldn't articulate my ask well (Link to original thread: [Dynamic Nested Loops for Autofilter in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155905/dynamic-nested-loops-for-autofilter-in-excel-vba?answertab=active#tab-top)).  But now I have actually written the program to the way I like except using a switch statement instead of the more dynamic use of nested looping.

**edit:**
RSum is used to store a range and a boolean. The user selects the header cell for a column and chooses whether they want get a summation of that column or a unique count when summarizing. This allows for a collection of these objects to allow summarizing of multiple columns. This input wasn't so bad to make dynamic.  The next input which starts as rtemp and ends as array1, is again the user selects the header cell for a column but this it takes the values in that column and saves a unique list to array1. With this list a for loop loops through the array using its value as criteria for an autofilter.  For each step in the loop after the autofilter, the summary is calculated using the SumThisA taking the RSum object collection as an input.  The data is laid out in columns where each row is a unique record.

So the question is, for the below code, I want the user to be able to select the number of categories to summarize by, have a popup to fill in those ranges (can figure this out), and then run a filter as such:

```
for i = 0 to UBound(array1)
    Autofilter criteria1:=array1(i)
    for j = 0 to UBound(array2)
        Autofilter criteria1:=array2(j)
        ......
            for x = 0 to UBound(arrayx)
                Autofilter criteria1:=arrayx(x)
                aSum(i,j,....x) = somefunction
```

Now I understand I would need to use a recursive function, but having never used one before and the somewhat complexity of this program, it is out of my understanding.  Would anyone be able to help explain how to use it in this context?  Plus because of the generalization of this program, it could be a useful tool for many people.

```
'---------Initialize Arrays---------------'
t = sMax - 1
Dim aSum()
ReDim aSum(UBound(arr1), t)  

'---------------------Perform Summary----------------'
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
If i = 0 Then
    Data.AutoFilter field:=afield, Criteria1:=arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Else
    Data.AutoFilter field:=afield, Criteria1:=arr1(i)
End If
temp = SumThisA(SumValues, sMax)
    For j = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
        aSum(i, j) = temp(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Sum of Dollars For:
 1. arrayA(1)-------100
    - arrayB(1)------30
    - arrayB(2)------70
 2. arrayA(2)-------200
    - arrayB(1)-----120
    - arrayB(2)------80
 3. Total-----------300

Comment: It would help a lot if you could describe your expected inputs and outputs: small example datasets would be great. That's a lot of code to go though and figure out.  For example what is "RSum" ?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I added in the description in my original post.  How do I load a small dataset onto here?

Comment: All that appears to matter is the function you want, but it would sure help if you were more concise and specific.  Also, in the future, please don't post another question, edit your original.

Comment: Well the function I need is one that will allow me to get a summary of array2 (theoretically arrayx) as a subset of each item in array1 (theoretically array(x-1)).  I also would need a better way of storing these values as my current method is multidimensional arrays (not shown but I use 3D arrays for when I have two categories).

Comment: The heart of your question seems to be: `So the question is, for the below code, I want to the user to be select the number of categories to summarize by, have a popup to fill in those ranges (can figure this out), and then run a filter as such:`, but then I lose you with your code. An autofilter means something very specific in Microsoft Excel. It's what happens when you select Data->Filter->AutoFilter. Is that what you want? Could you please start from scratch and only post the **specific** bits of code you are having problems with?

Comment: ok thanks transistor.  I cut down the code to the area I need help with.  The program will prompt the user for the number of categories.  It will then create x arrays based on that number.  I then need to loop through the arrays and apply the autofilter as crudely written in the first code block.

Comment: @riotburn: I admit to still having no idea what you're trying to produce here.  You can create small sample input and output tables just by typing them into code blocks.

Comment: OK, based on what seems to be your real issue, getting the array filled based on a recursive process, I've given an answer.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Tried to make a sample output table at the bottom of my original post

Comment: Not sure if you can tell but the arrayA(1) is a subtotal of arrayB(1) and arrayB(2) that are below it.

Comment: I have finally gotten a sample input and output together. [Link to Sample](http://tinypic.com/r/fdr0wi/7) If the picture helps, the point of the recursion is to keep applying filters in different fields as the desired output gets broken down by more categories.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very kludgy example of recursion for what it seems you want to do.  I faked up some criteria, so don't get hung up on how I'm testing for that, what's important is how the function Filter functions recursively.  If I could pinpoint more exactly what you wanted I could craft it more precisely, and with less hardcoding.

Test Harness:

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim FilteredArray As Variant, cArray As Variant, working Array As Variant
Dim criteria As Integer

criteria = 1
ReDim criteriaArray(1 To 2)
cArray(1) = Range("C1").Value
cArray(2) = Range("C2").Value
Set workingArray = Range("A1:A7")
FilteredArray = Filter(workingArray, 7, cArray, criteria)    
Range("D1") = FilteredArray    

End Sub
```

Recursive Filter Function:

```
Public Function Filter(workingArray As Variant, index As Integer, _
                       criteriaArray As Variant, criteria) As Variant

Dim tempArray As Variant, i As Integer

ReDim tempArray(1 To 1)
For i = 1 To index
  If Mid(workingArray(i), criteria, 1) = criteriaArray(criteria) Then
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(1 To UBound(tempArray) + 1)
    tempArray(UBound(tempArray) - 1) = workingArray(i)
  End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve tempArray(1 To UBound(tempArray) - 1)

If criteria < 2 Then
  Filter = Filter(tempArray, UBound(tempArray), criteriaArray, criteria + 1)
Else
  Filter = tempArray
End If

End Function
```

Comment: First off, thank you for taking the time to help me out.
  
Are you saving the criteria arrays to an array of arrays and then passing that to the filter function?  Also, I am not sure how the filter function is working, could you walk me through it?

Comment: @riotburn, no, I'm just creating one criteria array, which could be filled in many ways, but it has to be a variant to pass to a function.  My Filter function filters an array to a subarray based on a criteria (which can be changed any way you want), then it filters the subarray based on a different criteria, and so on.

Comment: Please don't worry about my test for the criteria, I just made something up to highlight recursion.  I don't really get why you're using Autofilter, but that doesn't mean it's not the right approach, I just don't have any experience with Autofilter in VBA.

Comment: I have finally gotten a sample input and output together. [Link to Sample](http://tinypic.com/r/fdr0wi/7) If the picture helps, the point of the recursion is to keep applying filters in different fields as the desired output gets broken down by more categories.

Comment: @riotburn, I'm having a real hard time seeing your relationship between input and output in the picture, so it's not really clearing things up.  They look completely disconnected.

Comment: The values don't correlate but I was merely trying give an idea as to how the data is formatted.

Comment: Yes, but there's not enough for me to understand yet what you're doing.  For example, you have no gender column in the data, so where does that come from, somewhere else?  No age column either.  So in the end I still don't understand how you want to go from input to output.  I'm sure that you need to simplify things, since if your question can't be made any simpler, then there's probably an uneccessary level of complexity, but I can't tell you where exactly.

Comment: [link to better example](http://i53.tinypic.com/24xi6p1.jpg)  I apologize I was at work and made up something quickly.  Thank you for your time and patience in trying to help me solve this.  I have posted a better example. To note: the filters dont get cleared until the next i.  If I am still not clear, I have finished making a userform that can output something in the format of Table 1 which I could send you if you are willing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a pivot table ?  Your requirements seem very close to that functionality...

Comment: its almost exactly like a pivot table but a pivot table doesn't have a unique count ability.